# Estimating number of data points in specific range from percentile data

Tags: estimation, quantiles

If I have a dataset broken down into percentiles, such that I know there are *n* values, and 10% of these values fall below *x1*, 20% are below *x2* and so on, how can I estimate an answer to the following question:

How many values fall below *x*, for arbitrary *x*?

Or more specifically:

How many values are between *x* and *y*?

Note that the intervals between percentiles are not uniform.

In case I am on the wrong track, and in case it helps, here is the actual problem:

---

I have a set of data for UK gross annual earnings per job, broken down into percentiles:

10  20  25  30  40  50  60  70  75  80  90 91   92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99

I want to calculate the gross income tax for any arbitrary set of tax bands, e.g., how much revenue would the Treasury receive in one year if income tax rates were 0% on the first £10k, 10% on £10k-£20k, 15% on £20k-£30k, 25% on £30k+